# Correct way to encode Kinect audio with lame.exe

Tags: audio, kinect, lame

I receive data from a Kinect v2, which is (I believe, information is hard to find) 16kHz mono audio in 32-bit floating point PCM. The data arrives in up to 4 "SubFrames", which contain 256 samples each.

When I send this data to lame.exe with `-r -s 16 --bitwidth 32 -m m` I get an output containing gaps (supposedly where the second channel should be). These command line switches should however take stereo and downmix it to mono.

I've also tried importing the raw data into Audacity, but I still can't figure out the correct way to get continuous audio out of it.

EDIT: I can get continuous audio when I only save the first SubFrame. The audio still doesn't sound right though.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with Ogg Vorbis. A free format, so no problems there either. I use the following command line switches for `oggenc2.exe`:

```
oggenc2.exe --raw-format=3 --raw-chan=1 --raw-rate=16000 - --output=[filename]
```